# How can I return a variable number of containers of various types?

Tags: c++, boost, generic-programming, boost-mpl, boost-variant

I have data that looks like this:

```
     token            eps  rank # first line names columns
 Intercept   9.362637e+00     1 # later lines hold data
        A1  -2.395553e-01    30
        G1  -3.864725e-01    50
        T1   1.565497e-01    43
....
```

Different files will have different numbers of named columns and the types of values in each column will vary among floats, ints, and strings.

I want to write a `readCols` function to which i send names of columns (e.g. I may want the `token` and `rank` columns) which will put the the data in the specified column into containers of the appropriate type.

My problem is not in parsing the file but in returning a variable number of containers which contain different types.  For instance, I want the `token` and `rank` columns put into `vector<string>` and `vector<int>` containers, respectively.   The issue here is that I may want the `eps` column instead (stored in a vector), and I don't want to write a different `readCols` function for every conceivable combination of types.  (The type of container doesn't matter to me.  If I have to only use `vector`s, no problem; that each container contains a different type is the key.)

I'll probably need a container that holds different types to hold the different types of container.  It looks like [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant.html) might be the solution I want, but I don't know how to tell the parser which type I want each column to be (could I make something like a list of typenames? e.g. `void readCols(string filename, vector<variant<various types of vector>> &data, vector<string> colNames, vector<typename> convertTo)`).  Likewise, [Boost.Mpl.Vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html) may solve the problem, but again I can't quite figure how to tell `readCols` how each column wants to be cast.

I can think of at least two workarounds:

1. Read each column separately with a templated function that reads into any container (`container::value_type` allows the function to know how to parse).  I don't prefer this solution because the files are occasionally large (millions of lines) so parsing them multiple times would take an extra few minutes (not a negligible percentage of run-time in programs whose calculation takes ~30 minutes; the program will run over and over).
2. Read all columns into containers of strings and re-cast them in the calling context rather than in the parsing context.  This wouldn't be so bad, as I think I can do the conversion in one line with `std::transform` and `boost::lexical_cast` or s/t.  If I can avoid `2n` lines of bloat, great (`n`=number of columns, typically 2 or 3, 2 lines per column to declare the container and then transform).

It may be that the second workaround will require significantly less effort from me than a complete, generic solution; if that's the case, I'd like to know.  I imagine that the second workaround might even be more efficient, but I'm mainly concerned with ease of use at the moment.  If I can write one generic `readCols` function and be done with it, that's what I'd prefer.

Comment: @jrok I never have, but it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When things get too complicated, I break the problem into smaller parts.  So here's a suggestion.

Write a CSV reader class which can read comma or other delimiter separated values from a file.  The class reads a line at a time and breaks the line into std::string fields.  In order to access the fields, you implement functions like getString, getInt, getDouble, etc that access the fields (by column name or index) and converts them to the appropriate type.  So the reader does a well defined thing and deals with a *limited* number of primitive types.

Then implement reader functions (or classes) that utilize your CSV reader.  These reader function know the specific types of the columns and where to put their values - either in scalars, containers, etc.

Comment: The idea of the reader makes sense.  Something like: `readerClass reader(file, colNames); while(reader.advance()) { vec1.push_back(getInt("col1")); vec2.push_back(getString("col2")); ... }`.  The main disadvantage would be that I'd have to reiterate such a loop for each file I read; I wouldn't be able to push that boilerplate into a separate function.

Comment: How many different files do you have?  Once you write one or two of the functions, you should be able to find commonality and factor that out into separate functions.

Comment: It would not be hard to write a different function for each type of file i have.  What's hard is writing one function to do all the work.

Comment: Why have one very complicated function when you can have a few simple ones?  I prefer small functions that do clearly defined things instead of having larger functions that do many things.  Much easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: I'm used to programming in perl, where type safety is not a concern.  Without type safety, there's nothing ill defined about this task.  I certainly hear you about debugging and maintenance concerns.

Comment: My goals here are to (a) make my life as a programmer easier and more fun, and (b) learn more C++.  I should say that I find the solution I posted below quite cumbersome, and accomplishes neither goal.  Your reader solution is conceptually clean and requires little boilerplate, and I voted for it.

Comment: Looking back, this answer is very much the right way to think about my question. I've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the types of return values are limited, e.g. `int`, `double`, or `std::string`, a function like this will do the job:

```
using namespace std;
void readCols(string fileName, vector<string> stringCols, 
      vector<string> intCols, vector<string> doubleCols, 
      vector<vector<string> > *stringData, 
      vector<vector<int> > *intData, 
      vector<vector<double> > *doubleData);
```

(Probably clear enough, but you list the column names you want according to what type they are.)

Whether this is more or less trouble than the workarounds is in the eye of the beholder.